# Is 70% ethanol hygroscopic?

Tags: concentration, alcohols

I'm currently doing some DNA extractions and I realized that in some protocols, they are saying that ethanol is [hygroscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygroscopy).

In [this source](https://www.beckmancoulter.com/wsrportal/bibliography?docname=AAG-666SP.pdf), they are saying:

> 85% ethanol made with nuclease free water (Note: 85% ethanol is hygroscopic. Fresh 85% ethanol should be prepared for optimal results)

I know that this is even more pronounced for 100% ethanol. But I'm wondering if

1. 70% is still "very" hygroscopic so that the concentration might change over time. Say differently, how stable is the ethanol concentration over time?
2. How long would a 70% ethanol solution last? That may depend on the volume made, but I want to know if there could be a "best before" date so that it's no longer considered as a 70% ethanol solution. A year? A decade? 2 minutes?

Comment: I think real problem is that it's volatile

Comment: So still it would change the concentration... but how fast?

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious, but isn't it sufficient to keep it in a tightly closed bottle? Hygroscopic just means it will absorb water from the air, but if you don't let it in contact with moist air...; and it won't evaporate that much either. I don't see the problem, unless you plan to keep if for years and the concentration must be incredibly exact (like "70.00%"  rather than "70%", and that would be pretty hard to achieve in the first place, because, as you pointed out, pure ethanol is very hygroscopic).

Comment: It is in a tight closed bottle. I don't usually put ethanol in the sink to pipet-it! :D But if you're telling me that it doesn't really matter, then I'll just prepare a larger amount, and I'll reuse this for a longer period instead of making 70 % ethanol each time I need it! I was just wondering how freaked out I should be by the "hygroscopic" phenomenon for 70% ethanol and especially if it could affect my results.

Comment: @user6376297, If you have a source, I'd like to see it!

Comment: A source? Just physics and logic... If you mix two pure substances that don't react with each other and then you store the mixture in such a way that it is not exchanging matter with any external system, what do you suppose would make the composition change? I guess your source means that opening and closing the bottle several times (that's when matter, and in particular moist air, is exchanged), may alter the composition by enriching it in water. How 'freaked out' you should be depends on how important having an exact concentration is for your application, and only you can tell that.

Comment: Estimating the amount of water that is absorbed each time you open the bottle depends on many factors: how big the bottle is compared to the volume of liquid it contains, the size of the neck, how long it stays open, the humidity in the lab, how the liquid is extracted from it... incredibly complicated for very little gain. In practice people will probably use a small bottle with a small neck, so that there won't be many open/close cycles, and not too much 'air' will enter each time. As a rough estimation, if you use about 100 mL at a time, I would make bottles of 500 mL.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you can have a look at this comprehensive [guide](http://ccc.chem.pitt.edu/wipf/Web/Air_sensitive_techniques.pdf) to handling air-sensitive material (which includes liquids that must not come into contact with moisture from the air). But frankly, for a solution that has got already 30% water in it, it would be ridiculous to go through such hassle...

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. That's what I roughly thought. But since I'm not a chemist, I just wanted to make sure I don't forget anything for basic chemistry.